# Using Subsonic for potentially heavily accessed ASPNET MVC Application

Tags: orm, subsonic, scalability

I am about to start a project for a potentially heavily accessed ASPNET MVC application and I was thinking to use Subsonic for my DAL.
I have some concern about the ability of Subsonic to handle thousands of concurrent requests.
Can anyone give me some examples of popular web sites using Subsonic? 
Also if you have any suggestion regarding a possible substitute to Subsonic, besides NHibernate,  that would be great as well.
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Thousands* of concurrent requests?  Are you sure that's likely?

For what it's worth, [DotNetKicks](http://www.dotnetkicks.com/) uses SubSonic, and never seems to have performance issues.

Answer (score 4):

I do about 4-5M requests a month through SubSonic without an issue, in fact it is super-quick and my server is hardly taxed. Those requests peak during the day so while we don't get up to 1000 concurrent requests I have been very impressed with SubSonic under load. Because it uses generated code it is actually going to be faster than most of the ORM you find out there.

Comment: You have a good point - generated code is a key factor for performance.

Answer (score 2):

SubSonic is a tool and you have to use it wisely like adding Caching to your site and closing the IDataReader if you use them sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

As a guideline, if you have 1000 users, you won't have more than 1 or 2 concurrent users. At least in my experience. To have 1K concurrent users you should have at least 500K-1M users.